# Accurately detecting checkbox state everytime with jQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Simply put: How can I use jQuery to detect a checkbox state reliably.

I have seen several versions of this question and most find a solution that works for them, in that scenario. However, none seem to work for me in this (seemingly straightforward) situation.

I have created 5 separate (but pretty similar) versions of the detection script. One works, but is too specific to be useful (works off ids for each chkbox) and the other 4 either detect both as checked, or both as unchecked.

I'd rather stick with jQuery to keep the code readable by all the other people working on this project (variety of JS levels), but if it is JS only then I guess that's better than it not working at all!

HTML (basically default Bootstrap3 inline-checkboxes);

```
<form>
    <p>Do you have a password?</p>
    <fieldset class="inline">
        <label for="radio-inline-1" class="block-label">
            <input checked="checked" type="radio" value="no" name="radio-inline-group" id="radio-inline-1">
            No, I want to create a password now
        </label>
        <label for="radio-inline-2" class="block-label">
            <input autocomplete="off" type="radio" value="yes" name="radio-inline-group" id="radio-inline-2">
            Yes, I already have a password
        </label>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

The JavaScript / jQuery

```
//Both detected as unchecked
$('.block-label input').each(function(){
    if ($('.block-label input').checked) {
        //checked 
    } else {
        //unchecked;
    }
});

//or if I want them both detected as checked
$('.block-label input').each(function(){
    if ($('.block-label input:checked').length > -1) {
        //checked
    } else {
        //unchecked
    }
});

//back to unchecked for prop
$('.block-label input').each(function(){
    if ($('.block-label input').prop('checked') === 'checked') {
        //checked
    } else {
        //unchecked
    }
});

//but strangely checked for attr
$('.block-label input').each(function(){
    if ($('.block-label input').attr('checked') === 'checked') {
        //checked            
    } else {
        //unchecked               
    }
});

//vanilla, ultra specific, JS to check that it IS actually possible to detect the state
var chkBox1 = document.getElementById('radio-inline-1');
var chkBox2 = document.getElementById('radio-inline-2');
if (chkBox1.checked) {
        //checked
} else {
        //unchecked
}
if (chkBox2.checked) {
        //checked
} else {
        //unchecked
}
```

I have put all of these methods in a fiddle and attached them to buttons for ease, but the real function has to run directly after the DOM has loaded (document.ready): https://jsfiddle.net/m1o4u10u/3/

Comment: there is a `change` event which you can bind to inputs, and you can see if an element is checked or not via `if ($(element).is(':checked')) {}`. Furthermore, I believe `prop()` returns a boolean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main issue is in the following two lines:

```
$('.block-label input').each(function(){
    if ($('.block-label input').checked) {
```

You are iterating through each input, but then retrieving *all* inputs inside the function. You should change it to:

```
$('.block-label input').each(function(){
    if ($(this).checked) {
```

But even that won't work because `.checked` is a DOM element property, not a jQuery property. It will work if you get the underlying DOM element:

```
$('.block-label input').each(function(){
    if ($(this)[0].checked) {  // Option 1
    if (this.checked)          // Option 2
```

But you could also just use jQuery to make it more readable:

```
$('.block-label input').each(function(){
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
```

Comment: That's great. Thanks for explaining it, it has been driving me nuts!

Answer (score 0):

All 5 method is working but we need to change few things. Your demo code is not properly use jquery selector. So you can view my edited version: https://jsfiddle.net/2hg5c8Ld/

I have replaced your code as per below:

## Try 1 case

```
$('.block-label input').checked
```

into this one

```
this.checked
```

#### expl: use "this" as current for each selector

## Try 2 case

```
($('.block-label input:checked').length > -1)
```

into this one

```
$(this).is(':checked')
```

#### expl: use "is" to check ":checked" selector

## Try 3 case

```
$('.block-label input').prop('checked') === 'checked'
```

into this one

```
$(this).prop('checked')
```

#### expl: use current selector "$(this)" and .prop return boolean

## Try 4 case

```
($('.block-label input').attr('checked') === 'checked'
```

into this one

```
$(this).attr('checked')
```

#### expl: use current selector "$(this)" and .attr return boolean

Hope it will helps...

Comment: sorry..someone already explained while iam typing all this stuff.